# Java Programming: Null Image?

Tags: java

OK, so I'm making a java game, I have a menu that has 3 buttons, start, help and quit, when I press the start button, it's suppose to load the tilemap and the player and then you can play the game, and sometimes it works completely fine with no errors, but sometimes the game freezes and comes with this error:

**TILEMAP ERROR**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TileMap.TileMap.draw(TileMap.java:180)
    at GameState.Level1State.draw(Level1State.java:73)
    at GameState.GameStateManager.draw(GameStateManager.java:36)
    at Main.GamePanel.draw(GamePanel.java:93)
    at Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And the error is targeted here:

```
g.drawImage(tiles[0][tilemap[i][j]].getImage(), 
        (int)x + j * tileSize,
        (int)y + i * tileSize,
        null);
```

And it will sometimes it will come with this error

**PLAYER ERROR**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MapObject.Player.draw(Player.java:82)
    at GameState.Level1State.draw(Level1State.java:74)
    at GameState.GameStateManager.draw(GameStateManager.java:36)
    at Main.GamePanel.draw(GamePanel.java:93)
    at Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and target error is here:

```
g.drawImage(frames[count], (int)x, (int)y, null);
```

The error means that the image is null, right? if it does then I don't get why it does that because no parts of the image is null, so erm... pls help?

This is the coding to loading the tilemap if you need it

```
public void loadTiles(String s) {
    try{
        tileset = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(s));

        numTilesAcross = tileset.getWidth() / tileSize;
        tiles = new Tile[2][numTilesAcross];


        for(int col = 0; col < numTilesAcross; col++){
            subimage = tileset.getSubimage(col * tileSize, 0, tileSize, tileSize);              
            tiles[0][col] = new Tile(subimage, Tile.NORMAL);
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and for the player

```
public void loadImage(String s, int objSize) throws IOException {
    this.objSize = objSize;     
    image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(s));        
    width = image.getWidth();
    height = image.getHeight();     
    numAcross = width / objSize;        
    frames = new BufferedImage[numAcross];

    for(int col = 0; col < numAcross; col++) {
        subimage = image.getSubimage(col * objSize, 0, objSize, objSize);
        frames[col] = subimage;
    }
}
```

In Advanced: Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Why don't you use a debugger and figure out what's null?

Comment: It's difficult to spot any problems, if the shown code is not [self-contained](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Alternately, print out `g`, `frames[count]`, `x`, and `y` to diagnose the player error.

Comment: Are those methods being called by the same thread as the one where the error occured?

Comment: debugger won't help at all and will only confuse if this is a race condition as I suspect it is. The key word is "Sometimes"

Comment: If the error happens at `g.drawImage(frames[count]..`, I think this does not mean that the *image* is `null`, but that the `frames` array is `null`. Some debugging (or even just some `System.out.println`s) should help to quickly find out what's wrong there, though...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you may have a race condition: display versus image fully loaded.

You can use the [MediaTracker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/MediaTracker.html) to track that your image has fully loaded before you try to display it

(From the Javadoc)

```
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
      if ((tracker.statusAll(false) & MediaTracker.ERRORED) != 0) {
          g.setColor(Color.red);
          g.fillRect(0, 0, size().width, size().height);
          return;
      }
      g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this);
      if (tracker.statusID(1, false) == MediaTracker.COMPLETE) {
          g.drawImage(anim[index], 10, 10, this);
      }
  }
```